# Software version of network switch for VMs

Tags: networking, vmware, lan

I have hosted two images (both 2003 servers) from my VMServer. Including my desktop (xp-pro) there are three host.

I would like to connect them in a network (local LAN) without a physical switch.

Is there any software switch so that I can run in my desktop OS and let images use that interface to get IP automatically so that I can access Images from desktop OS?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use [dynamips](http://www.ipflow.utc.fr/index.php/Cisco_7200_Simulator) (+ [GNS3](http://www.gns3.net/)), but just use VMware's virtual infrastructure:

http://www.virtualizationadmin.com/articles-tutorials/vmware-esx-and-vsphere-articles/installation-deployment/vmware-understanding-virtual-switch.html

i.e. You need to upgrade to at least ESX, now it's vSphere.

**edit:**  Oh you really are on very basics of using a virtual machine:  just use bridged networking:

[image: Bridged networking connects a virtual machine to a network using the host computer's Ethernet adapter.]

http://www.vmware.com/support/ws55/doc/ws_net_configurations_bridged.html

Comment: The host will get its IP when the machine connected to DHCP Server. In my case I have VMServer and Image in my laptop. OS in laptop is windows... but I wanted to communicate (atleast connect Linux VM) running on VMWare Server running as an application in my laptop